# Firebase verifying email while being logged in

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following logic in my iOS app:

- User registers
- Firebase sends an email confirmation
- Returns to login screen

Now if the user logs in, without verifying the email, then we have a user session and `isEmailVerified` is false.
I only need to check the `isEmailVerified` in a certain point in the app.
Also I think signing the user in, checking the field and signing the user out would be bad practise.

I'd need to reauthenticate the user, what is the best way of doing this? How can I, after the user has logged in, switch the status of `isEmailVerified`?

Thanks

Comment: Would be helpful to add code... but you yourself cannot switch the status of isEmailVerified.  It gets switched when the user verifies his email.  You said need to check it only at a certain point in the app.  So, just before that point in your app, call   user(isEmailVerified) and will return the current status.

Comment: but what if the user signs in, then gets to the point of the app, it says “Please verify your email”, then the user verifies the email and gets back to the app while still being signed jn, then isEmailVerified is still false.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do now.  See below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to have the email and password to create a credential.  Your user already provided this on the login page... So the email and password to persistent storage on iOS.  In Android, the equivalent would be SharedPreferences.

I do not code in iOS, but this will give you the idea for the logic.

Then, when you get to that point in your app where email verified is called:

```
if (user.isEmailVerified) == true {
   // you do not need to hold the email and password in persistent storage anymore.
   // go into your persistent storage and delete the data.
} else {
   // get the email and password the user saved in persistent storage.
   String email = persistentStorage.getEmail();
   String password = persistentStorage.getPassword();

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
    user.reauthenticate(credentials);

    // then, when finished reauthenticating, check whether isEmailVerified() == true;


}
```